# Replacing the deprecated NSWorkspace launchedApplications function?

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion

In the documentation of `NSWorkspace` for `launchedApplications` function it says:
"It is strongly suggested that you use the `NSWorkspace runningApplications` method and the `NSRunningApplication` class to retrieve this information in applications targeted for Mac OS X v10.6 and later."

I'm looking for a way to retrive only the "real" applications that have a user interface, ignoring all the background processes like `loginwindow` or `Mac_SwapperDemon` etc.

This was automatically done in calls to `launchedApplications` and I can't find a way to do it with `runningApplications`.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want the apps in `runningApplications` whose `activationPolicy` is `NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular`.

Comment: [An anonymous user comments](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/206069): "Yes that's correct, although it's runningApplications and not launchedAplications that have the the activationPolicy. Thank you for your kind answer."